# How to get overloaded functions in autocomplete window in Vim using the clang_complete plugin?

Tags: vim, overloading, clang-complete

I'm new to vim and I have installed clang_complete with default settings and using it for C++.

I am able to use the autocomplete but whenever there are overloaded functions, I can only see one of them in the autocomplete window (which opens when you type . or -> ). I think clang shows only the first overloaded function that it encounters.

For example, when is type `aList.er` I can only see the declaration of `iterator erase(iterator)` and not other one with two iterator parameters in the autocomplete window.

Is there any way so that I can get all overloaded functions in the autocomplete window?

PS: I'm using ubuntu and Vim v7.3